# Android - Explanation about AsyncTask in Service class

Tags: java, android, service, android-asynctask

I've a task to running service every 3 second, the service will execute `asynctask` to checking `sqlite` and sending data into server

Code of `myService.class`

```
/* import foo.foo.foo */

public class myService extends Service {
    public Runnable mRunnable = null;
    private boolean mRunning = false;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public myService getServerInstance() {
            return myService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("Service"," onstart kepanggil ga?");
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Service","SERVICE RUN");
                SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("wit_player_shared_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String servcheck = pref.getString("serviceChecker", null);
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                int countFlagAuditID = db.getCountFlagAuditID();
                int countNeedToSend = db.getCountContact();
                if (countNeedToSend > 0){
                    Log.d("countNeedToSend : ", String.valueOf(countNeedToSend));
                    sending a = new sending();
                    try {
                        if(servcheck.equals("no")){
                            Log.d("Service","SERVICE TRY CALL SENDING");
                            a.execute().get();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (countFlagAuditID > 0){
                    Log.d("countFlagAuditID : ", String.valueOf(countFlagAuditID));
                    if(servcheck.equals("no")){
                        Log.d("Service","SERVICE TRY CALL SENDGET");
                        sendget b = new sendget();
                        b.execute();
                    }
                }
                db.close();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3 * 1000);
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3 * 1000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    //async task
    private class sending extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String >
    {
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("SENDING", "start sending");
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("wit_player_shared_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        pref.edit().putString("serviceChecker", "yes").commit();
        if (serv.equals("yes")){
            Log.i("stop service", "service di stop");
            stopSelf();
        }
      }
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
      //send data to server
      }
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("wit_player_shared_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
         pref.edit().putString("serviceChecker", "no").commit();
      }
    }
    private class sendget extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String >
    {
      //execute post to server
    }
}
```

I've a list of question about the code above:

1. to let my service run every 3sec I need to declare twice of `mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3 * 1000);`, if I'm declare the code just one, the service will run once, why it can be like that?
2. on `sending asynctask` I've add `stopSelf()` on `onPreExecute()` that mean the service will stop, but why `doInBackground()` task keep run?

Comment: any idea please?

Comment: `to let my service run every 3sec` You are not doing that. You start your service once with startActivity() outside your service. Then your service runs until stopSelf().

Comment: `a.execute().get();` Always a bad idea to use `.get()` on an AsyncTask. The whole design of your service is very strange. You use a handler to do the work. Where you should do the work directly in a thread and only use a handler for gui actions.

Comment: `I've add stopSelf() on onPreExecute()` Strange that you do that in onPreExecute(). Dont start the task i would say if you wanna stop. But indeed that stops your service but it does not destroy the task. Strange construct too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use timer instead of handler

```
private final Timer mTimer = new Timer();

mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new LocationUpdateTask(), 0, 3000);

private class LocationUpdateTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            //Do your stuff
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

        } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError in) {

        }


    }
}
```